# Relating $|f(z)-f(z_0)|$ to $|z-z_0|$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function defined on the compact convex region $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and let $z,z_0\in D$. I know that one can show (letting $\gamma$ be the line connecting $z$ to $z_0$)
$$|f(z)-f(z_0)|=\left|\int_{\gamma}f'(\xi)d\xi\right|\le\int_{\gamma}|f'(\xi)|d\xi\le\sup_{\xi\in D}|f'(\xi)|\cdot |z-z_0|$$
However I am trying to find a way to relate $|f(z)-f(z_0)|$ to $|z-z_0|$ in such a way that I would have
$$0<(\text{something})|z-z_0|\le |f(z)-f(z_0)|$$
Where the "something" term does not involve $|z-z_0|$. Note $z\neq z_0$. 
If needed I would be fine adding more constraints to the function $f$.

Comment: A region is not usually compact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course conditions are needed, since it's quite possible to have $f(z) = f(z_0)$ (a holomorphic function is  not always one-to-one).  One useful condition: Suppose for some constants $\omega$ with $|\omega| = 1$, $\epsilon > 0$,
$\text{Re}(\omega f'(\xi)) \ge \epsilon$ for all $\xi \in D$.
 Then with $(z - z_0)/|z - z_0| = \alpha$, 
$$ |f(z) - f(z_0)| \ge \text{Re}\left( \frac{\omega}{\alpha} (f(z) - f(z_0))\right) = |z - z_0| \int_0^1 \text{Re}(\omega f'(z_0 + t (z-z_0)
))\; dt 
\ge \epsilon |z - z_0| $$